# How to read information in .ply file

Tags: python, ascii, point-clouds, depth, zed-sdk

i want to understand the point cloud data generated by zed. and my saved .ply file looks like this

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 1614755
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
end_header
-1.911526 1.159542 -2.212860 149 145 136
-1.909242 1.159433 -2.212651 150 146 137
-1.906777 1.159213 -2.212233 149 146 139
-1.906022 1.160034 -2.213798 150 147 140
and so on…
```

I know I got this .ply file from depth image sized(1920*1080) generated by zed camera.
I want know after the end_header how the data is arranged?

I want to compare this data with the depth image. where this `-1.911526 1.159542 -2.212860` `149 145 136` particular data is mapped in the depth image? is it top left corner? or top right corner or center? and the information in .ply belongs to which pixel in the depth image? is there any way to understand this data with depth image?